# Animate from current state

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm rotating and scaling a rectangular using inline styles. In Javascript I hold current state:

```
var currentScaleIndex = 1;
var currentRotateDegree = 45;
```

When user turns a rectangular I take current values and add new value to obtain new styles to apply:

```
var currentScaleIndex = 1;
var currentRotateDegree = 90;
```

The problem is that the animation doesn't happen from the current style, as in:

```
<div style="transform: scale(1, 1); rotateX(45deg);"
```

to

```
<div style="transform: scale(1, 1); rotateX(90deg);"
```

But from the beginning style where there was no scale or rotate set. How can I solve this?

Comment: A demo along with your JS and animation would help.

Answer (score 0):

Maximus,

Rotating X axis with 90 degree will never show anything on page as its perpendicular to the page, if try checking the x axis with 100 degree, 110 degree, 120 degree, you will come to know how it works.

If you want to rotate it exactly opposite, you can move it to 180 degree.

Hope this will work!!

Cheers!!!